# Rounding to 3 Decimal Places - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, decimal, rounding

I am creating a code to convert force in lbs to force in newtons.  I got everything to convert correctly, but can't seem to figure out why the Math.Round method isn't working.

```
    btnConvert.Enabled = true;



        double pound;
        double force;
        double conversationRate;

        double.TryParse(txtForce.Text, out pound);


        conversationRate = 4.44822;

        force = pound * conversationRate;
        Math.Round(force, 3);

        txtForceN.Text = force.ToString();
        Math.Round(force, 3);

        btnConvert.Enabled = false;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Math.Round does not alter the value. It returns a new one instead.

```
var newVal = Math.Round(oldVal, 3);
```